# SQL Merge into getting stuck

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I want to Merge into some data from a (python) panda dataframe to my sql-server 2019 running on azure.

This is my code with example data values:

```
MERGE INTO [dbo].[APPSCHED_CNG] AS t
USING (
    VALUES
        (53243, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 80000, 20230621, 90000, 0, 0),(53259, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 123000, 20230621, 133000, 0, 0),(53266, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 93000, 20230621, 103000, 0, 0),(53234, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 80000, 20230621, 80000, 0, 0),(53286, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 80000, 20230621, 120000, 0, 0),(53272, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 123000, 20230621, 153000, 0, 0),(51509, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 74500, 20230621, 74500, 0, 0),(53247, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 80000, 20230621, 110000, 0, 0),(53255, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 80000, 20230621, 80000, 0, 0),(53236, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 93000, 20230621, 123000, 0, 0),(53251, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 93000, 20230621, 113000, 0, 0),(52915, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 100000, 20230621, 110000, 0, 0),(53238, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 100000, 20230621, 120000, 0, 0),(53239, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 123000, 20230621, 143000, 0, 0),(53284, '2023-06-19 12:39:35', 20230621, 143000, 20230621, 153000, 0, 0)
) AS s ([KEY], [change], [ANNDAT], [ANNZEIT], [ENDDAT], [ENDZEIT], [RG], [DATAGRP])
ON t.[KEY] = s.[KEY] AND t.[ANNDAT] = s.[ANNDAT] AND t.[ANNZEIT] = s.[ANNZEIT] AND t.[ENDDAT] = s.[ENDDAT] AND t.[ENDZEIT] = s.[ENDZEIT] AND t.[DATAGRP] = s.[DATAGRP]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([KEY], [change], [ANNDAT], [ANNZEIT], [ENDDAT], [ENDZEIT], [RG], [DATAGRP])
    VALUES (s.[KEY], s.[change], s.[ANNDAT], s.[ANNZEIT], s.[ENDDAT], s.[ENDZEIT], s.[RG], s.[DATAGRP]);
```

What it should do:
I have this data from a IBM db2 database. When I open the frontend, the backend should check DB2 for new datasets. If the datasets are not on the Azure-SQL, the new datasets should be inserted - exept, if there is a difference only at RG, so a different RG is not relevant if there is a difference.

And here is the table script:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[APPSCHED_CNG](
    [KEY] [int] NULL,
    [change] [datetime] NULL,
    [ANNDAT] [int] NULL,
    [ANNZEIT] [int] NULL,
    [ENDDAT] [int] NULL,
    [ENDZEIT] [int] NULL,
    [RG] [int] NULL,
    [DATAGRP] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it causes the SSMS to load and load and load and it looks it do not find an end..

What seems to be the problem with my code?
Is it a problem that I did not support `WHEN MATCHED THEN`?

Thank you

Comment: Merge was introduced with SQL Server 2008 and still has its share of problems even today. If you only need to update then update. If you only need to insert then insert. Try to avoid merge unless it's completely unavoidable.

Comment: What does "When I open the frontend, the backend should check DB2 for new datasets" mean? Does it have any relevance? Can the problem be boiled down to the sample SQL you have provided? Or is there more to this? As already mentioned, since you are only inserting I recommend that instead of  `MERGE` you use `INSERT INTO SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS` or something along those lines

Comment: Do you really need so many columns to uniquely identify a row `KEY, ANNDAT, ANNZEIT, ENDDAT, ENDZEIT, DATAGRP` can you not narrow it down to a shorter list of unique columns? Then make a clustered primary key across those columns.

Comment: As others suggested if you want only to insert the rows then its better to use inert with condition instead of merge and also use indexing on key or column that you want to compare so it will improve performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INSERT INTO SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS` as written in the comments brings the solution.
Here updated code:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[APPSCHED_CNG] ([KEY], [change], [ANNDAT], [ANNZEIT], [ENDDAT], [ENDZEIT], [RG], [DATAGRP])
                        SELECT s.[KEY], s.[change], s.[ANNDAT], s.[ANNZEIT], s.[ENDDAT], s.[ENDZEIT], s.[RG], s.[DATAGRP]
                        FROM (
                            VALUES
                                (51509, '2023-06-19 15:59:31', 20230621, 80000, 20230621, 74500, 0, 0),
                                (53247, '2023-06-19 15:57:31', 20230621, 80000, 20230621, 110000, 0, 0)
                                --rest of values            
                        ) AS s ([KEY], [change], [ANNDAT], [ANNZEIT], [ENDDAT], [ENDZEIT], [RG], [DATAGRP])
                        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                            SELECT 1
                            FROM [dbo].[APPSCHED_CNG] t
                            WHERE t.[KEY] = s.[KEY]
                                AND t.[ANNDAT] = s.[ANNDAT]
                                AND t.[ANNZEIT] = s.[ANNZEIT]
                                AND t.[ENDDAT] = s.[ENDDAT]
                                AND t.[ENDZEIT] = s.[ENDZEIT]
                                AND t.[DATAGRP] = s.[DATAGRP]
                        );
```

Comment: You should be certain that those 5 columns are really a composite unique key.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: I want to check if there was a change in this columns, and values are only inserted when there is any change in these five columns - `KEY` is not really primary key - it is from other DB in DB2 the `KEY`